# In ASP.NET MVC, what is the equivalent of ASP classic's server side includes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I have been developing in classic ASP for about 2.5 years and I am trying to update my skill set to include ASP.NET MVC.

What is the MVC way of executing SSIs? IE: How can I include a database drawn navigation list in a sidebar? I have been looking into partial views, but they seem to get their content from the controller. As far as I can tell this means that I would need to write each controller to pass the navigation list.

Am I thinking along the right lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options that are similar to SSI

1. Use either RenderAction or Action ([explanation of the difference between the two](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx))
2. If you're using MVC2 there's also [DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390.aspx) helper method which would allow you to define a custom display template for a particular object.

In your case Option 1 is probably the better one since you probably don't want to contain the items for the menu in your view model/view data.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to using RenderAction() (which has some drawbacks because it must run the entire ASP.NET request pipeline to get its output), you can use a BaseController type that all of your controllers inherit which overrides OnActionExecuted() to insert values into the ViewData collection. With this approach you will then have the benefit of using a single request, and still not having to worry about manually adding cross cutting data to your model every time you handle a request.

To keep things simple I like to use a `public const string SomeDataItemViewDataKey = "Controller.DataName";` in the controller class definition to key the ViewData entry added by the controller and then in the view when I need to render that output I can use templated helpers to pull the value from the ViewData: `<%=Html.DisplayFor(ControllerType.SomeDataItemViewDataKey, "PartialViewUsedToRenderTheData") %>`.

---

#### Update

Because there's been some confusion about the validity of my statement, here is the original source of the performance claims against RenderAction():

> Yes, there is a signficant difference
>   in performance of RenderAction
>   (slower) vs. RenderPartial (faster).
>   RenderAction, by definition, has to
>   run the whole ASP.NET pipeline to
>   handle what appears to the system to
>   be a new HTTP request, whereas
>   RenderPartial is just adding extra
>   content to an existing view.
>
> -Brad Wilson, Senior developer on the ASP.NET MVC team

Quote source: http://forums.asp.net/p/1502235/3556774.aspx#3556590

Brad Wilson's blog: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/

#### Update 2

Here's the code from RenderAction() in the MVC2 RTM sources where we can see that although there is a new request being fired, it actually isn't going through the whole ASP.NET pipeline *anymore*. That being said, there are still some minor although mostly negligible drawbacks to using it over the alternative of PartialViews and ViewModel/ViewData. From what I understand (now) there was an overhaul on the implementation of RenderAction() prior to being moved from the MvcFutures assembly into the core framework; so it may hold that the statement above from Brad Wilson was more valid when he made it 6 months ago than it is now.

```
internal static void ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) {
    if (htmlHelper == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("htmlHelper");
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName)) {
        throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "actionName");
    }

    routeValues = MergeDictionaries(routeValues, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
    routeValues["action"] = actionName;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName)) {
        routeValues["controller"] = controllerName;
    }

    bool usingAreas;
    VirtualPathData vpd = htmlHelper.RouteCollection.GetVirtualPathForArea(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, null /* name */, routeValues, out usingAreas);
    if (vpd == null) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.Common_NoRouteMatched);
    }

    if (usingAreas) {
        routeValues.Remove("area");
    }
    RouteData routeData = CreateRouteData(vpd.Route, routeValues, vpd.DataTokens, htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    HttpContextBase httpContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
    RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData);
    ChildActionMvcHandler handler = new ChildActionMvcHandler(requestContext);
    httpContext.Server.Execute(HttpHandlerUtil.WrapForServerExecute(handler), textWriter, true /* preserveForm */);
}
```

Comment: "(which has some drawback because it must run the entire ASP.NET request pipeline to get its output )" - This isn't true.  RenderAction packages the existing request and starts a new MVC rendering lifecycle. RenderAction does not create a new Asp.net request pipeline.

Comment: @jfar If you'll note my updates, I have added the source of this *true* claim.

Comment: Nice, I had the source for MVC preview 2 open instead of RTM when I looked at your claim.  My mistake.  Awesome that you followed up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, partial views are the way to go. The controller should be handling the presentation logic. Similar to the code behind of web forms and web controls.

I would also utilize the master page for things like navigation.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I've never used stack overflow before so i really appreciate the feedback.

Just to clarify; if I want the same db drawn navigation on every page, then I need to write each and every control to grab that model for the partial view?

The reason I ask for clarification is it seems (in my old-school way of thinking) that classic asp SSIs seem to be far less labor intesive.

Comment: As a former ASP programmer, you will have to break the thought process of ASP to ASP.NET. They are just too different. To alleviate adding a control to partial view to every view I highly recommend my second recommendation, using a master page. It gives you the navigation in a single place that can be included on every page.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right and this is something you want to have an every page, RenderAction could be your friend.

Comment: Yes you understand my question correctly. RenderAction? cool... I'll go google that.